# How to retrieve info from database to display with Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write my first chrome extension. The workflow goes something like this -When the extension is installed and active if a user hovers over a specific product/ID displayed on the page, the extension retrieves related vendor data about the product with the ID.

This is how I thought about this:

1. Use jQuery attr to access the ID on mouse over.
2. Post this ID to a retrieve.php file with .post() method
3. The retrieve.php file retrieves the data from database
4. Display the data in a tool tip on the web page.

I have some queries for the above process:

1. I am able to get this working on a local XAMPP server but how will it work online as the chrome extension will not have access to server. What is the way around to retrieve data without using PHP?
2. I am able to get the logic working but am unable to place these in respective files - Will all my logic reside in background.js ?

Any suggestions on getting this started will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a very simple API on your server that responds with JSON to any request it receives after processing it. Like this:

```
{"firstVar":"foo","secondVar":"bar" }
```

Your chrome extension can then make an xmlhttp request to this server and and process the returned data.(You could also use JSONP and wrap the response in a callback function which will execute as soon as you have the reponse)

The JS extension will be able to deal with the JSON nicely as it can understand that format so you can then choose to display the data in whatever way you want.

Essentially, what you want is a server that can take an ID posted to it and return the corresponding date in a nice and readable format. And a chrome extension that can make an request to a server and then process the response. Build and test them separately (keep positing an ID to the server and see the response and for your JS side at first instead of making requests to your unfinished API just set a static response to begin with which will be the same as an expected response.

Comment: Hi Tomi - Thanks for the reply! This is a little over the head for me.. Can you provide some information on building this API? Or any other method?

I am trying to do this using the $.ajax() function from Jquery. Any pointers in this regard?

Comment: So when you create your php file (retrieve.php) once it gets the information out of the database it should return it to the page in a very simple way. Using the ajax method from jquery is fine, just send the ajax request to the php page you created with the necessary post variables and save the response to a javascript variable and process it.

Comment: Yes. I was thinking on similar lines. I use the $.ajax() - post to end the data and then write a $.get() to fetch the data from the PHP script or can I do it from the success callback of the first $.ajax() request only? I am unable to see if the $ajax request will return data in success callback or it just says the query was a success/failure.

Comment: Send a $.post to the server like this:
 
    `$.post( "http://yourdomain.com/retrive.php", { id: "33"})
      .done(function( data ) {
        alert( "Done: " + data );
      });`


This way inside the .done function the "data" variable will be the repose from your server which you can process how you want.

You don't need to do 2 separate post and get requests. Send the ID and the process the resposne the server gives in one go

Comment: Before trying to build a chrome extension that connects to your API you should probably just set aside a few hours to play around with the javascript xmlhttp request or at least the jquery $.get, $.post stuff.